# Calculating Big O notation: O(n^4) for 2 nested loops and O(log n) with no recursion

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

It's been a while since I've done some runtime complexity approximation exercises and I have been trying to wrap my head around the following examples that found online *(the comments are my own)*:

**Example 1:**

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) { //n
  for ( int j = 1; j <= i*i ; j++) { // 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2
    if ( j % i == 0) {
      for ( int k = 0 ; k < j ; k++ ){ // 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2
        sum++;
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

The solution sheet says it is O(n^4), but I can't see it. I'm sure there is something I missed because in my comments I counted that in the worst case it is of O(n^5).

**Example 2:**

```
i = 1 ;
L2 = -1;
while ( i <= n ) {
  i = i*2 ; // 2 + 2^2 + 2^3+ ...+ 2^n
  L2++;
}
```

The mentioned solution is O(log n). I figured that in the worst case I'll get something along the lines of 2^n <= n, thus n <= log n. Here it was more intuitive to apply the typical definition of an upper bound function (i.e. f(n) <= O(g(x)) )

I am basically wondering what I missed, and what steps/guidelines I should have undergone to find the correct big O complexity for both cases (especially the 1st example).
I apologise for any unclear details and I'm happy to add more clarifications.
Thanks in advance and I appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is `O(n^5)` because big-O is an upper bound. It's also `Theta(n^4)` because the if statement makes the innermost loop run only every `i` iterations, so the running time is `Theta(n sum_{i=1}^n (i*i * 1/i * i*i)) = Theta(n^4)`.

Example 2 is `O(log n)`. In the `j`th iteration, `i` is `2^j`, and the threshold for `2^j > n` is `j > lg n`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while it does seem straightforward, could you perhaps elaborate your work, especially for example 1? I didn't quite get this: Theta(n sum_{i=1}^n (i*i * 1/i * i*i))